# rich:datascroller binding HtmlDatascroller.getPage() problem

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I have jsf 1.2 and richfaces 3.3.3.Final.

I have a binding of rich:datascroller in my java.
A weird thing happens though: getPage() method sometimes returns the right page numbers and sometimes the wrong ones.
What's wrong with that?

The component in jsf:

```
<rich:datascroller id="tableScroller" renderIfSinglePage="false" for="projectPlanCreatetable" pageIndexVar="pageNo"
         binding="#{ProjectPlanCreateControl.listAction.scroller}" >
         <a4j:support event="onpagechange" action="#{ProjectPlanCreateControl.pageChanged}" reRender="visitedPages"
                 oncomplete="markPages();"/>
</rich:datascroller>

<h:inputHidden id="visitedPages" value="#{ProjectPlanCreateControl.visited}" />
```

and the javascript:

```
function markPages(){
      var pages = document.getElementById('mainFrm:projectPlanCreatetable:visitedPages').value;
      pagesArr = pages.split(",");

      for (var i=0; i<pagesArr.length-1; i++){
          jQuery('td.rich-datascr-inact').filter(function() {
              return jQuery(this).text() == pagesArr[i];
          }).css('color','red');
      }
}
```

The java:

```
public String pageChanged(){
     HtmlDatascroller scroller = listAction.getScroller();           
     visited += scroller.getPage() + ",";
     return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, found it.
I should've used the page attribute to get the page in my Controller, and not binding.